# difference between "cnt += num % 2;",and, "if (num % 2) ++cnt;"

Tags: c, binary, global-variables

the difference between "cnt += num % 2;",and, "if (num % 2) ++cnt;"
I succeeded in counting the number of '1' in binary number.
but one line which seems to do the same thing makes different result.

global variable  "cnt=0" is declared top of the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int cnt=0;

//and the recursive function which counts '1' is here
int one( int num ) {
if (num < 2)
{
 cnt += num;
  return cnt ;   //here, escape and return cnt to main. 
}                      
else
    {
        one(num / 2);
        cnt += num % 2; //according to the remainders cnt++ AND THIS IS THE THE QUESTION CORE
    }
}

void main() {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    cnt=one(num);  //call recursive function
    printf("%d", cnt);  //and here, i want to watch the [RESULT]
}//main
```

[RESULT]

when I use  " `cnt += num % 2;`  "  prints correct answer
but another code which seems same    "`if (num % 2) ++cnt;`" prints wrong answer.

num%2 must be 0 or 1. so it adds '1' to cnt. but second code doesn't work.

which point did i miss?

Comment: Do your function `one` return in all cases? A function declared to return a value *must* do it, or you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Talking about returning values, the `main` function is specified in the C specification to always return an `int`.

Comment: my test case is just natural number bigger than 1.

Comment: Please read my first comment again. What do you ***return*** if `num >= 2`?

Comment: That is 'else{}' case. so, it calls 'one(quotient ) '  function. and it piles up stack until it meets 'num==1'

Comment: That's okay, but what do you ***return*** in the `else` branch? Nothing! You never return anything, leading to the above mentioned *undefined behavior*. And since you have Undefined Behavior (or UB as it's often abbreviated) there is no meaning in discussing the behavior of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Other than lack of `return` in `else branch`, you use global var `cnt` in a .. not an appropriate way (those are what you missed). The following code works well:

```
int one(int num) {
    if (num < 2) {
        return num;
    } else {
        return (num % 2) + one(num / 2);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.